# Passing a dictionary to a sklearn classifier with base_estimator features

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, iterable-unpacking

I am trying to pass a dictionary to a sklearn classifier to set its parameters but I would also like to set `base_estimator` features for example:

```
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
>>> x = {'n_estimators': 200}
>>> clf = AdaBoostClassifier(**x)
>>> clf
AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
      learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=200, random_state=None)
```

Works fine but if I try:

```
>>> x = {'base_estimator__max_depth':5}
>>> clf = AdaBoostClassifier(**x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 
'base_estimator__max_depth'
```

I have also tried setting the base estimator beforehand i.e. `AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(),**x)` but this also doesn't work with the same error as above.

I realise it can be set doing `clf.base_estimator__max_depth = 5` but I would ideally like to unpack a dictionary that sets multiple parameters of the classifier. So my question is, is this possible and if so how?

Note: I know how to set these parameters I would just like to know if it is possible to do it by unpacking a dictionary as this looks nicer to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats because the python constructor for AdaBoostClassifier has only the following parameters defined in the `__init__()`:

```
base_estimator=None,
n_estimators=50,
learning_rate=1.,
algorithm='SAMME.R',
random_state=None
```

And for it `base_estimator__max_depth` is an unknown parameter.

However, you can use the [`set_params()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.set_params) which will handle them correctly according to the documentation:

> Set the parameters of this estimator.
>
> The method works on simple estimators as well as on nested objects
>   (such as pipelines). The latter have parameters of the form
>   **component__parameter** so that it’s possible to update each
>   component of a nested object.

So you can do this:

```
x = {'base_estimator__max_depth':5}
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier())
clf.set_params(**x)
```

**NOTE**: In python 3 you can also do the following (which is what I think you are looking for):

```
x = {'base_estimator':DecisionTreeClassifier(),
     'base_estimator__max_depth':5}
clf = AdaBoostClassifier()
clf.set_params(**x)
```

The above is broken for python2 currently and will be fixed in next version. See [issue here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9944).

Another way is that you can always first set the dictionary to the DecisionTreeClassifier and then pass that to the AdaBoostClassifier.

Something like this:

```
x = {'max_depth': 5}
base_est = DecisionTreeClassifier(**x)
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator = base_est)
```

Do you have something else in mind? If yes, please post the complete code snippet of what you want to do and we can find a way.

Comment: The first way works nicely for me, currently I am restricted to work with Python2 on this issue, i'll keep an eye out for the when the python 3 solution is fixed for python 2. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.